# UNION ALL You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: sql, mysql

I am using Union All for two select query. Both side the query is different I have to find the records from both table and show. I have tried below query but I am getting error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'as table2' at line 4

```
SELECT * FROM 
(select company_id as ID,concat('https://example.com/axy/',`slug`) as url from company22 c where company_name like '%xyz%' and c.is_active = 1 and admin_approved = 1 order by company_id desc limit 0, 1 ) as table1
UNION All
 (SELECT ID, post_title, post_content, post_date FROM `wp_posts` where post_content like  '%xyz%'  and post_status = 'publish' and post_type='table' order by post_date DESC ) as table2
```

Comment: Please format your SQL to be readable - horizontal scrolling is hard work.

Comment: Syntax errors aside, it does not make sense to union two completely different result sets. Why are you trying to union these two queries?

Answer (score 1):

To get that to work, you can make from the UNION a subquery, or don't use the outer select at all

```
SELECT * FROM 
((select company_id as ID,concat('https://example.com/axy/',`slug`) as url , NULL , NULL from company22 c where company_name like '%xyz%' and c.is_active = 1 and admin_approved = 1 order by company_id desc limit 0, 1 ) 
UNION All
 (SELECT ID, post_title, post_content, post_date FROM `wp_posts` 
 where post_content like  '%xyz%'  
 and post_status = 'publish' 
 and post_type='table' 
 order by post_date 
 DESC )) tab1;

(select company_id as ID,concat('https://example.com/axy/',`slug`) as url, NULL. NULL from company22 c where company_name like '%xyz%' and c.is_active = 1 and admin_approved = 1 order by company_id desc limit 0, 1 ) 
UNION All
 (SELECT ID, post_title, post_content, post_date FROM `wp_posts` 
 where post_content like  '%xyz%'  
 and post_status = 'publish' 
 and post_type='table' 
 order by post_date 
 DESC )
```

Comment: @nkb, I have tried first query and I am getting error  #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: There are possibility of getting multiple result in in first select query

Comment: @NarenVerma Yes a UNION needs both or more result sets that have the same number of columns. i changed my answer to demonstrate how it must look like

Comment: I am getting this error  #1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION' then I have tried COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci in the first select query before as URL and now I am getting error  #1060 - Duplicate column name 'NULL'

Comment: which charcterset an collation has your table probablay utf8mb4 so you need to convert url to the same collation, which of course i don't know

Comment: Ok. I got the output. let me check with PRD server. Please allow me some time.. I have tried null AS col1, null AS col2 instated of NULL in first query

Answer (score -1):

The error message tells you that you have a syntax error in your query of

```
 SELECT *
FROM   (
                SELECT   company_id                                         AS id,
                                  Concat('https://example.com/axy/',`slug`) AS url
                FROM     company22 c
                WHERE    company_name LIKE '%xyz%'
                AND      c.is_active = 1
                AND      admin_approved = 1
                ORDER BY company_id DESC
                LIMIT    0, 1 ) AS table1
UNION ALL
          (
                   SELECT   id,
                            post_title,
                            post_content,
                            post_date
                   FROM     `wp_posts`
                   WHERE    post_content LIKE '%xyz%'
                   AND      post_status = 'publish'
                   AND      post_type='table'
                   ORDER BY post_date DESC ) as table2
```

It is because you are trying to select from a non-table. Let's do our first improvement and convert your union into a table (**this will still be incorrect**). You had two tables you generated, but their union was not a table.

```
 SELECT *
FROM   (
       (
                SELECT   company_id                                         AS id,
                                  Concat('https://example.com/axy/',`slug`) AS url
                FROM     company22 c
                WHERE    company_name LIKE '%xyz%'
                AND      c.is_active = 1
                AND      admin_approved = 1
                ORDER BY company_id DESC
                LIMIT    0, 1 ) AS table1
union ALL
          (
                   SELECT   id,
                            post_title,
                            post_content,
                            post_date
                   FROM     `wp_posts`
                   WHERE    post_content LIKE '%xyz%'
                   AND      post_status = 'publish'
                   AND      post_type='table'
                   ORDER BY post_date DESC ) AS table2 )
```

Next, the problem is that your `table1` and `table2` have very different column lists. This spells disaster. Make sure that the column list in the two tables look similar.

Finally, it is very probably wrong logically to have `company_id` at the same field place as post id. So you will need to think your query through again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I have tried your answer but i am getting error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union ALL
          (

Comment: @NarenVerma I have emphasized in my answer that **this will still be incorrect**. I have improved your query, but have not fixed it. You will need to take into account the schema of your tables as well as the data-set you have. If you want my help to be more practical, then you will need to provide your table schemas, some sample data, hopefully in an already executable manner in a SQL Fiddle.